# Schedule events via EventBridge with details

Tags: amazon-web-services, eventbrite, aws-event-bridge

I want to schedule events via Event bridge, so that
Event Bridge will send the events to SNS and subscribe with SQS, then in my springboot application i will listen to SQS ..

but the problem here is, i cannot find a way to provide details in this event.

i want to send something like this:

```
 {
  "version": "0",
  "id": "89d1a02d-5ec7-412e-82f5-13505f849b41",
  "detail-type": "Scheduled Event",
  "source": "aws.events",
  "time": "2016-12-30T18:44:49Z",
  "detail": {"use-case-name": "Update all customers"}
}
```

is there any possibility i can put details in there?

i try to configure like this

[image]

but the event is still does not have any information in details

```
{
    "version": "0",
    "id": "7e62a5fa-2f75-d89d-e212-40dad2b9ae43",
    "detail-type": "Scheduled Event",
    "source": "aws.events",
    "resources": [
        "..."
    ],
    "detail": {}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Target](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/APIReference/API_Target.html)'s Input or InputTransformer attribute to send information to target (SNS/SQS in your scenario). You can pass a static JSON message or modify input message depending on the event data.

Note: AWS Eventbridge console has these fields so you can test them without writing code. **You won't see target input information on sample event details** but if you go to SQS console and see available messages (Poll for messages), you can confirm that messages passed to SQS include the JSON string you defined in the EventBridge side.

SQS sample message:
[image]

Comment: thanks Marko, i actually tried that, could you please see my edited question, unfortunately i could not add pictures in the comment.. but still no luck...

details is still empty and i receive only empty messages in SQS therefore

Comment: in sheduled event the details is empty

{
  "version": "0",
  "id": "89d1a02d-5ec7-412e-82f5-13505f849b41",
  "detail-type": "Scheduled Event",
  "source": "aws.events",
  "time": "2016-12-30T18:44:49Z",
  "resources": ["arn:aws:events:...:rule/SampleRule"],
  "detail": {}
}

Comment: @curious You don't see that info on event details but if you goto SQS console and see available messages (Poll for messages), you can confirm that messages passed to SQS include the JSOn string you defined in the EventBridge side.

Comment: thank you so much for all the help